# Selecting jQuery elements involving parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider following scenarios and jQuery usage variants:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="wrapper">
    <li class="item">item 1</li>
    <li class="item">item 2</li>
    <li class="item">item 3</li>
    <li class="item">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Usage a.**

```
$('.wrapper').find('.item').addClass('active');
```

**Usage b.**

```
$('.item', '.wrapper').addClass('active');
```

My **questions** are

- Are they identical, in terms of functionality?
- Is one perform better than the other?
- Assuming they are identical, which one is considered as a better practise?

Comment: Firstly, sorry for very ambiguous question title and lack of summary before jump straight into example. I am having trouble finding the terminologies for the mentioned usages, hence I cannot even begin googling my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This  `$('.item', '.wrapper').addClass('active');`

would be internally translated as

`$('.wrapper').find('.item').addClass('active');`.

So i am sure that there is no difference between them.

```
//HANDLE: $(expr, context) 
//(which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
```

I just found the above comments in the [jquery source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=init)

Comment: Is there an existing jQuery doc that elaborates this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Performance result may be useful http://jsperf.com/

[image]